# Unable to detect if dataSnapshot is null or not under 'addChildEventListener()`

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have set up a Firebase database for my app & it looks like this:

```
app
 -category
  -subCategory
   -subSubCategory
```

I have an `addChildEventListener()` set up like this:

```
mDatabase.child("category").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override   
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            if (dataSnapshot != null) {

            } else {
                Log.d("dataSnapshot", "null");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

I want to show an alert to user when the database is empty so I tried it by deleting everything in database and then it looked like this:

```
app: null
```

but even now the condition having line `Log.d("dataSnapshot", "null");` is not getting called.

**EDIT:**

I added

```
mDatabase.child("category").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot != null) {
                    Log.d("dataSnapshot", "AVAILABLE");
                } else {
                    Log.d("dataSnapshot", "NULL");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

and I got `D/dataSnapshot: AVAILABLE` printed out. How is this possible when there is no data in the database?

Why is this happening and what can I do to show users alert when the database is empty?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38551013/android-firebase-retrieve-data-from-child-node

Comment: @NirmalVaghasiya which are are you referring to?

Answer (score 2):

The `dataSnapshot` object itself will never be `null`. But you can ask if it's got any data, by calling `dataSnapshot.exists()`. So:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
        Log.d("dataSnapshot", "AVAILABLE");
    } else {
        Log.d("dataSnapshot", "NO DATA");
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried `dataSnapshot.getValue() == null` and it worked. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Why not use `dataSnapshot.exists()` as I did in my answer?